# How to use design resource in lightning component to provide string type attribute as picklist

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have changed my design resource to this

```
<design:component label="DeveloperGuideTest">
        <design:attribute name="PickOne" datasource="value1,value2,value3" default="value2"/>
    </design:component>
```

I have this in my component

```
<aura:attribute name="PickOne" type="String" access="global"/>
```

Now I couldn't figure it out how to use it as picklist on component.

Answer (score 5):

Design attributes are used to setup your component in App Builder.
So your code we'll be used when you open App Builder and drag & drop your component on the layout. You'll see at the right your attribute appear as a picklist.

If you want to use a picklist directly inside your component, you should use an attribute of type list of String instead:

```
<aura:attribute name="Picklist" type="String[]" access="global"/>
```

And then you can associate it to a component like [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm).

If the list is static, you may not even need your attribute, and add the values directly inside `lightning:select`.